# Inline code with lot of spaces overflow on the right side

Tags: bug, code-block, whitespace

If I write something like `` `Hello World` `` (or ```` ```Hello World``` ````) and then put a lot of **spaces after "Hello"** but **before the space** (before " World"), it will make the inline code overflow on the right side.

Here is an example:

`Hello                                                                                                                                                                                         World                                                                                                                     Test                                                                                                                                                                     abc`

Here is a screenshot if it doesn't work on your browser:

[image]

Another example I saw on [a post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677759/errnoeconnrefused-connection-refused-connect2-test-helper-rb/20085642#20085642):

[image]

I'm on **Ubuntu 18.04.4**, I tried this bug on **Google Chrome 81** and **Opera 68** and it worked as in the screenshot.

I also tried on Firefox but the bug doesn't work, there is no overflow.

Comment: The correct way to create a code block is to put the 3 backticks on separate lines, not on the same line as the code. What you have there is inline code (code which is meant to be on a line of text). So I don't think this is a huge issue.

Comment: [It overflows underneath the Community Bulletin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOTsn.png).

Comment: @KodosJohnson I've replaced the term and added an example from SO. It might not be a huge issue but since new users often don't know how to use format code using backticks, it can happen sometimes.

Comment: Related: [Comment Overflow?](/q/361250/289905).