# Question Summary Text Outside Border

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, code-formatting

If text is formatted as code in a question and that text is used for the summary on the Questions page it will go past the border of the summary.

[image]

[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039946/ifs-with-isnumbersearch-vba)

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, Chrome Version 98.0.4758.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I wonder how it looked with the old /questions page

Comment: @Makoto Probably similar to [this](//i.stack.imgur.com/ZG2Jp.png) (found on `/search`). The old design had `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;`.

Comment: why are the badges of the OP gone? Now it only says something like *username 13 asked 1 hour ago*... 13 asked ???

Comment: @Vickel See the report by [TylerH](/a/375153/289905) (about the removal of badges) and the one by [user673679](/a/375482/289905) and [ChrisW](/a/375494/289905) (about the format).

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks, looks like I only saw it today for the 1st time, I was not included in the first badge of users to try it out

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but this question might be related: [Inline code with lot of spaces overflow on the right side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347630/inline-code-with-lot-of-spaces-overflow-on-the-right-side)

Comment: Ah, they’re [about to fix](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/852) it.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed:

> [image: Image of text "not" overflowing out of the question summary border]

The text no longer overflows out of the question summary border.

(Tested on Windows 11 64-bit, Chrome version 101.0.4951.54)